# batch file showing folder size but does not show size of subfolder(s) and subfolder(s) from that subfolder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My batch program does show the size of the desired folder but does not show the size of the folder including the sub-folders. It just skips them. How do I make the program see the total size of a folder?

Program here:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:: folder choose
echo enter desired directory
set /p dir=
cd /d %dir%
::getting folder size
for /f "tokens=3" %%a IN ('dir /a-d /-c') DO (
   set size=!free!
   set free=%%a
   )
echo free space is %free% bytes
echo size is %size% bytes
```

thanks in advance!

Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply missed to add the `/s` option to the `dir` command:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FOLDER=" & set /P FOLDER=""
for /f "tokens=3" %%A in ('
    dir /S /A:-D /-C "!FOLDER!"
') do (
    set "SIZE=!FREE!"
    set "FREE=%%A"
)
echo free space is %free% bytes
echo size is %size% bytes 
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

To see size of folders on the Desktop.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Desktop"') do set doc=%A

for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

To see size of folders the System32 folder.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%windir%\system32" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

See `Findstr /?`